# Java ASM Instruction Searching

Tags: bytecode, code-injection

I've been using BCEL InstructionFinder so I am kind of spoiled.  The way I've seen ASM instruction find isn't really suiting my needs.  So, as I've seen so far I've only been able to search single instructions, would anyone be willing to part with or giving an example on using an Instruction Searcher with multiple strings.  Also, How would I call it when I do find it?  In BCEL you use InstructionHandle, and you just call the int array of the string you gave.

Thanks for the help.

P.S. If it helps, I'm only reading the class files, recognizing them.  Not modifying.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be easy enough to modify [TraceMethodVisitor](http://asm.ow2.org/asm33/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/util/TraceMethodVisitor.html) to build a String representation of given method. Then you can match such String with a regexp like InstructionFinder does.